# Setting auto-sequencing file names in netlogo

Tags: csv, netlogo

I am exporting a results table from netlogo to .csv and would like to have it change the file name in sequence each time.

For example the first run on of the session would be file_1.csv the second file_2.csv etc.

I see how to do this manually, but is there a way to automate it? I'm guessing it has something to do with

```
if file-exists? = TRUE 
   [file-open "file_?1.csv" 
      ask patches [ "say stuff"]
   file-close]
```

but I'm missing something. any advice is always appreciated!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the first run on of the session".  If you really mean "the first run of the experiment", you can use `behaviorspace-run-number`, which holds the number of the current run (starting at 1).

Comment: I'd prefer it to do it by session (each time the program is opened), but this works too. How do I incorporate it in to the file name though? Putting the " " around the file name just straight pastes it, rather than running the code

Comment: `(word "file_" behaviorspace-run-number ".csv)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file-exists?` takes a string as an argument. So you could do something like this:

```
let counter 0
let saved? false
while not saved? [
  let filename (word "file_" counter ".csv")
  if not file-exists? filename [
    file-open filename
    file-print "stuff"
    file-close
    set saved? true
  ]
  set counter counter + 1
]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Just a quick tip to anyone using that code: make sure you don't use ask patches [] to call it. I did by mistake on the first time, and it has every single patch create an output file (VERY space and time intensive, especially for large worlds).