# How do I export NetLogo 6.2 View when I have multiple turtle profiles?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to implement an output which is an export from the View. I got help from this link: [How to export the world of NetLogo 6.2 coloring only the patches that were born turtles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027107/how-to-export-the-world-of-netlogo-6-2-coloring-only-the-patches-that-were-born)
I greatly appreciate Luke C's help, as I managed to implement part of what I want.

However, I still haven't managed to generate the images by turtle profile. I have 16 turtle profiles (see ValidHabs).

I would like for example to export an image for each of the 16 turtle profiles.

For example, turtle profile 1 (can only born and hatch in habitatcover 1), so:

```
At tick 0, the world started with: 1 turtle no (patch 15 -4),
At tick 1, there are 2 turtles in patches (patch 15 -4) and (patch 14 -8) and
At tick 2, there are 4 turtles in patches (patch 15 -4), (patch 14 -8), (patch 12 -5) and (patch 17 -1).
```

So for the turtle profile 1 you would have a white exported image with the patches (patch 15 -4), (patch 14 -8), (patch 12 -5) and (patch 17 -1) painted magenta.
Then I would export an image to the profile of turtle 2 etc... until I get to the profile of turtle 16 that can only spawn in habitatcovers 4 and 5.

I tried to use a foreach to export the image to each profile, but what happens is that opens a single .png file and generates the results in that single file (“overwriting”). And what I would like is to generate 1 file in .png format for each turtle profile. I thought that using foreach and carefully I could generate the files. But so far I haven't been able to.

The code:

```
globals [ ListProfiles ]
patches-own [ turtle-born-here ]
turtles-own [ all-code  metabolism reproduction code-metabolism code-reproduction ]

to setup
  ca
  set ListProfiles [ [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] ]
  ask patches [ set turtle-born-here false ]
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    sprout 1
    setup-turtles    
    set turtle-born-here true
  ]  
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 60 - 30
    fd 1
    if random-float 1 < 0.05 [
      hatch 1
      ask patch-here [ set turtle-born-here true]
    ]
  ]
end

to setup-turtles 
  ask turtles [
    (
      ifelse
      metabolism = 2 [set code-metabolism "M1"]
    )
    (
      ifelse
      reproduction = 5 [set code-reproduction "R1"]
    )
    set all-code ( word code-metabolism code-reproduction )
  ]
end

to example-export-image
  setup
  ; Some example go runs
  repeat 50 [ go ]

  ; This is the export-view component
  cd
  ask turtles [
    ht
  ]
  ask patches [
    ifelse turtle-born-here
    [ set pcolor magenta ]
    [ set pcolor white ]
  ] 
  carefully
  [ file-delete ( "View.png" ) ]
  [ ]
  foreach ListProfiles
    [
      y ->
      let k turtles with [ all-code = y ]
      ask k [
      export-view ( "View.png" )
      ]
    ] 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, the code you supplied is way more than what's actually needed for the question itself, which for me would boil down to: "How do I change the file name for multiple experiments / simulations?" This question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129172/netlogo-changing-exported-file-name) [in different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380983/setting-auto-sequencing-file-names-in-netlogo) [that may suit your needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796314/editing-file-name-when-using-export-view-in-netlogo).

For a standalone example, that is really just a refinement of Charles' answer in the first link above:

```
patches-own [ hab-type turtle-born-here ]

globals [ profiles ]

to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 29 0 29
  set profiles [ "a" "b" "c" ]
  ask patches [
    ( ifelse pxcor < ( max-pxcor / 3) [
      set hab-type "a"
    ] pxcor < ( max-pxcor * 2 / 3 ) [
      set hab-type "b"
    ] [
      ; else
      set hab-type "c"
      ]
    )
  ]
end

to fake-simulate
  foreach profiles [ profile ->
    ask turtles [ die ]
    ask patches [
      set pcolor black
      set turtle-born-here false
    ]
    ask n-of 5 patches with [ hab-type = profile ] [
      sprout 1
      set turtle-born-here true
    ]
    reset-ticks
    repeat 50 [
      ask turtles [
        rt random 60 - 30
        fd 1
        if random-float 1 < 0.1 and [ hab-type ] of patch-here = profile [
          hatch 1
          ask patch-here [ set turtle-born-here true]
        ]
      ]
      tick
    ]
    export-image profile
  ]
end


to export-image [ unique-id ]
  ; Prepare the view for export
  ask turtles [ ht ]
  ask patches [
    ifelse turtle-born-here
    [ set pcolor magenta ]
    [ set pcolor white ]
  ]
  ; Use word to create a file name
  let out-file ( word "example_view_export_" unique-id "_.png" )
  export-view out-file
end
```

Outputs something like:

[image]

Comment: Hi Luke C. First of all thanks for your patience. I'm still having a lot of difficulty in generating clearer, reproducible, smaller examples that are not tied to the model I'm developing. But, I fully agree with you that this makes it difficult to understand and other people to use as help. That way, I tried to edit the code for better understanding. And sorry for any inconvenience. Next time I'll try to generate more specific code. Thanks for the help!